# Loading a file with complex-valued elements in Python

Tags: python, file-io, complex-numbers

I have a file with `filename="data.OUT"` with numerous lines such as

```
8  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.5  0.25  0.25  [(-5.254878050808644e-16+0j), (1.9349052915745023e-16+0j)]  [(-3.026872012243266e-16+0j), (3.380866562575897e-16+0j)]  
8  2.0  2.0  2.0  0.5  0.25  0.5  [(-2.4214426298686264e-18+0j), (0.0030397206475613592+0j)]  [(4.725139008075004e-19+0j), (0.0030696070416985225+0j)]
```

To read data from the file I have tried `np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=complex)`, which results in `nan+0j` data for complex-valued columns. I also have tried `np.loadtxt(filename,dtype=complex)`, which results in `ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string`.
In my search to find a solution, I encountered [this suggestion](https://blog.joey-dumont.ca/read-c-format-complex-numbers-with-numpy/) which also didn't help.

Do you have any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Numpy is expecting *individual* complex numbers, not pairs of complex numbers surrounded by `[]` and separated by `,`.

Comment: Correct! Do you have suggestions for reading this datafile?